# gawk gensub replacement deleting characters when using multiple patterns

Tags: regex, awk, substring, gawk

﻿The following is working as expected

```
echo -e "Abcd? Doi"| gawk '{print gensub(/([?]) ([A-Z])/, "_\\2", "G" ,$0)}'

-| Abcd_Doi
```

However when I use

```
echo -e "Abcd? Doi"|\
gawk '{print gensub(/([.]) ([A-Z])|([?]) ([A-Z])/, "_\\2", "G" ,$0)}'
```

I get

```
-| Abcd_oi
```

Interestingly if the matched pattern is the first in the '/...|.../' syntax then it is behaving as expected.

```
echo -e "Abcd? Doi"|\
gawk '{print gensub(/([?]) ([A-Z])|([.]) ([A-Z])/, "_\\2", "G" ,$0)}'

-| Abcd_Doi
```

Curious to know, why gensub will treat the position of the patterns in multiple "either" patterns differently? Any one?

I am using

> GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: It is default behevior common to all regex engines. In PCRE regex, there is a [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), but it is only a PCRE/Boost feature.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in your 2nd regex there are 4 captured groups and you need to reference group #4 in your replacement as:

```
echo "Abcd? Doi"|gawk '{print gensub(/([.]) ([A-Z])|([?]) ([A-Z])/, "_\\4", "G" ,$0)}'

Abcd_Doi
```

Here are group numbers in your regex:

```
/([.]) ([A-Z])|([?]) ([A-Z])/
---1------2------3------4---
```

---

You can actually combine both regex into one and deal with only 2 groups:

```
echo "Abcd? Doi"|gawk '{print gensub(/([?-]) ([A-Z])/, "_\\2", "G" ,$0)}'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That did work out, but raises another question- as there is no difference between gr2 and gr4, why it will gobble up the 1st character of the replacement string when \\2 is used? As for the code itself, my solution was gensub(/([.?] ([A-Z])/, _\\2, G, $0).

Comment: You can actually combine it into a single regex as: `/([?-]) ([A-Z])/` and then no need to deal with 4 groups. (see updated)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, see my previous comment. However, there must be a reason why gawk is treating the \\2 and \\4 differently.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Your original problem is not gawk specific. In any regex flavor if you are creating 4 captured groups in your regex then regex engine will create 4 groups.